# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime Manually Parse Date Value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I figured out I'm not parsing Date value as I should. But I'm unsure on how to do it.

I know I should manually parse date value, but to be honest I don't know how to do it.

```
 private void BtnDodajDavaoca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query = "INSERT INTO Davaoci (Ime,Prezime,Pol,DatumRodjenja,KrvnaGrupa,Tezina,Adresa,BrojTel,BrojLK) VALUES (@Ime, @Prezime, @Pol, @DatumRodjenja, @KrvnaGrupa, @Tezina, @Adresa, @BrojTel, @BrojLK)";
            using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-112OILD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DDK;Integrated Security=True"))
            using (SqlCommand InsertDavaoc = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
            {
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@Ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtIme.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@Prezime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtPrezime.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@Pol", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtPol.Text;
//IT'S THIS LINE InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@DatumRodjenja", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DtpDatumRodjenja.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@KrvnaGrupa", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtKrvnaGrupa.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@Tezina", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TxtTezina.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@Adresa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtAdresa.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@BrojTel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBrojTel.Text;
                InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@BrojLK", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBrojLK.Text;

                cs.Open();
                InsertDavaoc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();

                OsvjeziDgDavaoci();
                ClearTxtBx();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `TxtDatumRodjenja` is a TextBox control, substitute it with  `DateTimePicker`, so you don't need to parse a string, just take it's `.Value` property. The User input needs to be already validated when you pass it to your SQL, you cannot start the validation while in the add-parameters-to-the-query phase.

Comment: It is a DateTimePicker, but I named it TxtDatumRodjenja, it's the OCD thing in me. :)

Comment: Well, then take `TxtDatumRodjenja.Value` (that's the DateTime object), not it's Text property. The validation considerations stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe way in converting a string to a date is to use the `ParseExact` method, that allow you to specify the format in a deterministic way:

```
// Use custom formats with M and MM.
      var dateString = "5/01/2009 09:00";
      try {
         dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None);
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                           dateValue.Kind);
      }                           
      catch (FormatException) {
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use DatePicker instead of TextBox for this reason, but you can use Parse Method for parsing string to DateTime:

```
DateTime.Parse(TxtDatumRodjenja.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below code to convert your string date to dot net compatible date object like

```
InsertDavaoc.Parameters.Add("@DatumRodjenja", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DtpDatumRodjenja.Text);
```